# How to prove that this set is open.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

This is probably very easy. I know that it is very obvoius, but I want to prove it using the definition of what beeing open means.

I have $A = \{y \in R: y <a \}$.

And I want to show that it is open. I want to do this by showing that any point in A have an open ball, around it, which is contained in A.

So let x be a point in A. And then I have the ball $B(x,a-x)$, the radius is positive since a > x.

To show that the ball $B(x,a-x) \subseteq A$. I want to pick a point in $B(x,a-x)$ and show that this point is in A. But I get stuck:

$y \in B(x,a-x)\\ \downarrow \\?\\ \downarrow \\ y < a  \ \  \square$

I know this is so obvious by just looking at it, but I don't think I am allowed to say it is obvious.

Also, by the definition of the ball I get that
|x-y| <|a-x|, but this has absolute signs and is ugly, how do I transform this to y < a?

Comment: OK, then the next question is how can you get rid of the absolute value bars? When is |x-y| = x-y? When is it equal to something else? (What could that be?)

Comment: Ok, I will use that |x-y| < |a-x|, implies that |x-y|< a-x, since a is bigger, then x-y < a-x and y-x < a-x, the second gives that y < a. I see I had to use properties that are not general for metric-spaces, but particalr for the R space. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually, tp *show* that the ball is in $A$ you merely used the triangle inequality that holds in metric spaces as well. It is rater the choice you can make to pick the radius in the first place that makes use of properties of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen, but I didn't know how to use the triangle inequality to show it like it was a general space, when I splitted up the absolute values I am using that I am in R? But I see your point about choosing the radius, then I see I am using that I am in R.

Comment: This is very much related to the following post:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806027/prove-that-a-is-an-open-set-and-b-is-a-closed-set/806082#806082

Answer (score 1):

You have:
$$y\in B(x,a-x)\implies |y-x|<|a-x|$$
but $y-x\leq |y-x|$ and $|a-x|=a-x$, hence you obtain
$$y-x\leq |y-x|<|a-x|=a-x$$
from which $y<a$.