# Prove that $A$ is an open set and $B$ is a closed set.

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $E \subseteq \mathbb R^m$. Let $$A=\{x \in \mathbb R^m: \rho (x, E) < r\}, B=\{x \in \mathbb R^m: \rho (x, E) \le r\}.$$

Prove that $A$ is an open set and $B$ is a closed set.

Thanks ahead:)

Comment: Well, $\rho$ is continuous right?

Comment: Is $\rho$ the usual metric of $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: @user115595: Yes, it is!

Comment: Is this for a course on Spivak's "Calculus on Manifolds"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arbitrary union of open sets is open.  We certainly know that an open ball $B_r(x)$ (of radius $r$ centred at $x$) is an open set.  Behold:

$$A=\bigcup_{x\in E} B_r(x)$$

$B^c=\{x : \rho(x,E) > r \}$. So if $x\in B^c$, let $d=\rho(x,E)$ then $d>r$ so pick $\varepsilon >0$ such that $d -\varepsilon > r$ then by reverse triangle inequality $B_{\varepsilon} (x) \subset B^c$ thus the set is closed (it's complement is open). To see the last claim: Choose $x' \in \partial B_{\varepsilon}(x) $ then by the reverse triangle inequality we have $\rho(x',E) \ge \rho(x,E) -\rho(x,x')=d-\varepsilon > r$ (which proves the claim)

Comment: Special Case: If $r=\infty$ then the second proof doesn't technically apply (can't pick $d>r$) and just realize that $B^c=\emptyset$ (nothing can be further than "infinity distance"). As $\emptyset$ is (both) open (and closed) this shows $B$ is (both) closed (and open)

Answer (score -1):

Gvien $B_E(p,r)$ (with $r > 0$ y $p \in E$) y $q \in B_E(p,r)$, we choose $r′ =r − \rho(p,q)$, thus we have that $B_E(q,r′) \subseteq B_E(p,r)$, which is what you wanted to proof.